# how to select multiple images and videos in image from camera roll and display them in a collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been using following code to select an image and display it via UIImageView:

```
class ViewController UIViewContoller, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func loadImage(_ sender: Any){
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]){
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How can I use UIImagePickerController class to select multiple images and videos and display them in a collection view?

Comment: if i can't use UIImagePickerController for multiple images and videos what can i use?

Comment: I'm unsure of your goal but I think you'll need to make your own implementations that will interact with and display images/ videos from a user's library and select and import them as you desire. You can checkout: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html as a start if that's what you're after.

Comment: yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use UIImagePickerController class to select multiple images and videos

You can't. UIImagePickerController lets the user choose *one* image / video.

Comment: so which class should i use?

Comment: Use to do _what_? I think I answered the question as you asked it. I don't really know what your larger goals are.